# Audited Gem: tracking through multiple relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, audit, acts-as-audited

Looking for the right way to setup `audited associated_with` and `has_associated_audits` in my models its easier to track.

The Setup:
Publisher has exclusive dealer with Authors. An author can write many books. A Book can have many writers. A Book has one type of book binding. A book binding can have many books.

Goal:
Id like to be able to call Publisher.find(1).associated_audits to get everyone in one fail swoop.

```
class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  has_associated_audits

  has_many :books
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited associated_with: :publisher
  has_associated_audits

  belongs_to :publisher
  has_many :author_to_books
  has_many :books, through: :author_to_books
end

class AuthorToBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited associated_with: #????? this is where I need help
  has_associated_audits

  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :author
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited associated_with: #????? this is where I need help
  has_associated_audits

  has_many :author_to_books
  has_many :authors, through: :author_to_books
  belongs_to :book_binding_type
end

class BookBindingType < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited associated_with: #????? this is where I need help
  has_associated_audits

  has_many :books
  has_many :publishers, through: :books
end
```

Currently I can call `Publisher.find(1).associated_audits` and that gives me the associated audits for Author.

For Book I do: `Book.joins(:audits).references(:audits).joins(:authors).where(authors: {publisher_id: 1}).map(&:audits)`

For BookBindingType I do `Book.joins(:audits).references(:audits).joins(:authors).where(authors: {publisher_id: 1}).map(&:audits)`

As you can guess those last two queries, while taking into consideration time complexities...they both still take a bit of time to run when I start having more records.

The Question:
How can I setup the `????` parts of the audited gem to able to track. I know the polymorphic setup of the audits table only allows it to track one associated record at a time. So is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

For the few people that have looked; I haven't found an official `associated_with:` way of doing it. However I have dramatically increased the the processing time involved by directly querying the Audits table. I will eventually extend the Audits model with my own [custom audit model](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited#custom-audit-model), but for now I am doing:

```
Audited::Audit.where(auditable_type: 'BookBindingType', auditable_id: BookBindingType.joins(:publishers).where(publishers: {id: 1}))
```

This runs the query much quicker than the includes/joins I used in my question's description.